# TSQL - Omit prefix if it exists within a view (non-destructive)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

I have created a view in SQL Server using T-SQL which is working fine but have been recently been tasked with omitting a prefix found in some of our data. Specifically, I'm dealing with location names in which some of the data has our company name attached as a prefix, example: "XYZ Corp - New York". Not all of them do, but for the ones that do, my current project requires that I omit "XYZ Corp - " from the view without actually removing it from the data. Column name is "DBA" and Alias is "Location (DBA)".

I can easily do this within Excel, but am not quite sure how to do so within a SQL view...

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know exactly what data needs to be omitted each time? A simple `replace` in the view would suffice for a fixed string.

Comment: Yes, my only concern was I almost need an "IF". The data that needs to be replaced, when present, is always static and the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your view use the replace it as below, It will replace the "XYZ Corp - " with blank ..only if it exists else it will remain as is.

```
replace(DBA,'XYZ Corp - ','') as "Location (DBA)"
```

Sample output ....

```
select replace('XYZ Corp - New York','XYZ Corp - ','') as "Location (DBA)"
Output> New York

select replace('ABC Corp - New York','XYZ Corp - ','') as "Location (DBA)"
Output> ABC Corp - New York
```